# How can i visualize 3d cad models with react js not only with their geometry but also with their movements?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d-modelling

I have a React website with a 3d cad model. It's an Applicator for cards. So it has moveable parts and each of them have their own degrees of freedom. The project is about to visualize this machine, and to make it possible to interact with it manually. For example, to adjust the angle of the applicator arm. And with his movement the other single parts must rotate synchronously. Like gears. The movement of one gear wheel influences the movement of another gear wheel. It is exactly the same here. So would it be too complicated to define the position for each individual moving part? Should this perhaps be realized with a software or how? Unfortunately, I am completely new to this topic, so I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Thank you.

I tried to define every single moveable part but that is too time-consuming.
I hope there are other solutions.